# Porting Code to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, pascal

I wrote a game years ago (under Windows 95) in Pascal.  Since then over time I'd checked it and it still ran with the newer OSs.  It works in XP.  It works in Vista.  However under Windows 7, even in the XP compatibility mode, it crashes on the spot.

I've yet to get a chance to attach a debugger and wade through the decade-old code, but I was wondering if there's a definitive list of what changes under Win 7 may break code - API implementation changes or new protected memory spaces?  I know there are all sorts of marketing things showing the new or changed Features, but not how it affects developers...

It'll give me a place to start at least thinking about what it does, before I roll up the sleeves and dig in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371708%28VS.85%29.aspx

MSDN will be your best friend in this regard.